# Import csv files based on condition from the folders that inside another folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-import, python-os

I would like to copy and paste csv files based on conditions from folders inside another folder.

The main folder's name is “main”, and there are folders inside it, namely main_1, main_2, main_3,......, and main_45. There are also csv files inside each folder, namely, a1, b2, c3, d4, e5,........z30.

I just want to copy a1.csv, b2.csv, and c3.csv from the folders and paste them into another empty folder. It looks too complex to me, but I am sure it would be easy for experts. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need python for this.  A simple shell command will do.  `cp */a1.csv other_folder` And repeat for b2.csv and c3.csv.

Comment: The main idea is curiosity about how to do that using python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` iterates through directory and show all files in string.

So iterate through `main` folder and if the file name ends with `.csv`, then copy it with `shutil.copyfile` function

```
import os, shutil
for p, d, f in os.walk("main"):
    for fname in f:
        if fname.endswith(".csv"):
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(p, f), os.path.join("ANOTHER EMPTY FOLDER NAME", f))
```

docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: `if fname in ['a1.csv', 'b2.csv', 'c3.csv']:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want all CSV filenames under a certain folder and sub-folders, an easy approach would be to use Python's [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob%20glob#glob.glob) function. With this you can specify `*.csv` for just the CSV files and also make it recurse into sub-folders:

```py
import glob

for csv_filename in glob.glob(r'C:\main\**\*.csv', recursive=True):
    print(csv_filename)
```

If you only want to copy CSV filenames which start `a1` `a3` or `c10` for example, a regular expression could help:

```py
import glob
import os
import shutil
import re

re_abc123 = re.compile('[a-z]\d+')

for csv_filename in glob.glob(r'C:\main\**\*.csv', recursive=True):
    basename = os.path.basename(csv_filename)
    
    if re_abc123.match(basename):
        print(csv_filename)
        shutil.copyfile(csv_filename, os.path.join('output_folder', basename))
```